# Can partials be controller-specific?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, can partials be controller-specific? I have a controller for creating post and a view that went with it. After I renamed the view (added _) to make it a partial, it no longer seems to work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The short answer is yes. But you will need to share the code you are currently trying to use in order to get an answer that makes this work, also, what error are you getting specifically?

Comment: @RockwellRice The code is insignificant really. Simply def new end in controller and a view that was named the same as controller. The name now has _ in front. The url /controller/view no longer works, hence my asking. Very newbie question, sorry.

Comment: Do you have a view that's calling the partial?

Comment: If you want to call `new` view from `new` action, it should be prefixed with _. The prefix _ is only for partials, which you calls inside main views, `render 'form'` for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Partials are not views.

Partials cannot be rendered as views. Which makes perfect sense since partials are not views - they are reusable chunks of a view.

Lets say you have:

```
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end
end

# app/views/posts/new.html.erb
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

If you rename `new.html.erb` -> `_new.html.erb` Rails will no longer be able to find the view - because it no longer is a view.

## Can partials be controller-specific?

Partials are by there very nature controller-specific. For example:

```
# app/views/posts/show.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'foo' %>
```

Will look for `app/views/posts/_foo.html.erb`.

```
# app/views/stories/show.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'foo' %>
```

Will look for `app/views/stories/_foo.html.erb`.

Thats because Rails prepends the view lookup path with `app/views/controller_name`.

### Can views be shared?

**Yes.** But you need to explicitly tell Rails where the view is located.

```
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @resource = Post.new
    render 'resources/new'
  end
end

# app/controllers/stories_controller.rb
class StoriesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @resource = Story.new
    render 'resources/new'
  end
end
```

Or you could [append the view path](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/ViewPaths/ClassMethods.html#method-i-append_view_path).

```
class ResourcesController < ApplicationController
  prepend_view_path Rails.root.join('app/views/resources')
end

class PostsController < ResourcesController
  def new
    @resource = Post.new
    # will now default to rendering `app/views/resources/new.html.erb`
  end
end
```

### Can partials be shared?

**Yes.** But you need to tell Rails where the partial is located.

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/social_media_icons' %>
```